# How can I create a jar file with an entry point inside a file tree?

Tags: java, jar, entry-point

I am trying to create a jar file using this command:

```
jar -cef ./bin/a/MainClass formatter.jar ./bin/*
```

Where bin contains two folders with class files (lets say "./bin/a/" and "./bin/b/").

I can create the jar fine, but I can't seem to get it to execute properly. It runs without printing or doing anything. I assume it must not be using the entry point I supplied.

MainClass has a simple main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("HIT");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it necessary for the jar to be created in the same folder as the class containing main?

Edit: jar -tf as requested:

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Workspace\JavaAutoFormatter>jar -tf formatter.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
bin/a/
bin/a/MainClass.class
bin/a/ParsedFile.class
bin/b/
bin/b/Token.class
bin/b/Tokenifier.class
```

Comment: it may be helpful if you showed a 'jar -tf' so we could see the contents of the jar. and also hte class declaration for MainClass

Comment: @Martin, I don't believe this is a duplicate of that question. I know how to create an executable jar - I'm just not sure how to create an entry point using a class file hidden inside a file tree.

Comment: @Mike, added jar -tf output. All of the files are as I would expect them to be. I just don't think my entry point is working.

Comment: what is the package name of your classes?  should you be using -C bin?

Comment: @Martin, how would I check the package name of a class?

Comment: what is the `package` statement at the top of `MainClass.java`?

Comment: @Martin, 'package a;'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).  The argument for the `jar` command's `e` option should be a class name, not a path name.  Furthermore, when specifying the list of classes to be included in the jar, care should be taken to reference the files such that the directory structure matches the package name.  Otherwise the classpath lookups will fail.  Try:

```
jar -cef a.MainClass formatter.jar -C bin .
```

Answer (score 1):

> From **Wikipedia**
>   A JAR (Java ARchive) is a package file format typically used to aggregate many 
>   Java class files and associated metadata and resources (text, images,
>   etc.) into one file for distribution.
>
> JAR files are archive files that include a Java-specific manifest
>   file. They are built on the ZIP format and typically have a .jar file
>   extension.

```
jar cvfem <f input> <e input> <m input> input_files
jar cvfem Program.jar com.company.app.Main manifest.txt com net ..\img.png 
          ___________ ____________________ ____________ __________________
               ^                 ^               ^       ^
               |                 |               |       |
               f                 e               m      input files
```

Where

> - c = Create Jar File.
> - v = Verbose output. The verbose output tells you the name of each file as it's added to the JAR file.
> - f = Output to go to a file rather than to stdout.
> - e = Entry point in jar. For run jar files with  java -jar Program.jar.
> - m = Manifest extra data.
>
> Manifest.txt content
>
> ```
> Created-by: Joma
> ```
>
> - input_files = file, dir of your input files separated by space.

Resulted Jar Content

```
 __ com    
|  |__ company
|     |__ app
|     |   \ Main.class
|     |   \ Class1.class
|     |   \ Class2.class
|     |__ content
|        \ Class3.class
|        \ Class4.class
|        \ Class5.class  
|__ net
|   \ file1.txt
|   \file2.txt
|__ img.png
|__ META-INF
    \MANIFEST.MF
```